# Java - Native library issue

Tags: java, native

I'm getting in trouble with a native library for windows.

Here is the error I get:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\workspace\GameProject\src\lib\natives\jinput-dx8.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
```

For what I see, I got a compatibility problem with the DLL `jinput-dx8.dll`.

I really need this dll for my game but I don't know how to solve this problem. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to get/recompile a 64bit version of this library.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a 32bit JVM to load a 32bit native library.

Answer (score 0):

The architecture of the JVM and the native libraries have to match. You need a 32bit JVm to load a 32bit shared library and a 64bit JVM to load a 64bit shared library. Mixing both is not possible.